# Linking Zlib with source compilation

Tags: gcc, openssh, curl, makefile, zlib

I have compiled Libz using these steps:

```
wget -c --no-check-certificate https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.12.tar.gz
./configure --prefix=/home/zlib1/
make 
make install
```

Similarly I have compiled OpenSSL and also cURL. I have the respective `.so` (shared library file) linked in the Makefile as below:

```
export LD_RUN_PATH=$(PWD)/3rdparty/lib/zlib/:$(PWD)/3rdparty/lib/curl/:$(PWD)/3rdparty/lib/openssl/ 

LDFLAGS  = -L$(PWD)/3rdparty/lib/zlib $(LIBS) -L$(PWD)/3rdparty/lib/openssl -L$(PWD)/3rdparty/lib/curl $(LIBS_USR)
```

where `LIBS = -lz` and `LIBS_USR =-lcurl -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl`

When I compiled using the Makefile it was a success.

When I observed `ldd <binary>` (after compiling Makefile) I see that Zlib is taking system library path even though I have given the absolute path... all other packages are taking the absolute path.

`ldd` output:

```
libcurl.so.4 => /home/3rdparty/lib/curl/libcurl.so.4
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000055018f7000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 =>  /home/3rdparty/lib/openssl/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x0000005501927000)
libssl.so.1.1 =>  /home/3rdparty/lib/openssl/libssl.so.1.1 (0x0000005501bd9000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000005501c9e000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000005500000000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x0000005501e11000)
```

Why is zlib taking the system path instead of the absolute path?

How can I resolve this?

Openssl, curl and zlib are compiled using source and it was successful.

Comment: `--prefix=/home/zlib1/` would place `libz.so` in `/home/zlib1/lib` I think? which appears to be different from `$(PWD)/3rdparty/lib/zlib`

Comment: @steeldriver its my bad its not "--prefix=/home/zlib1/" it is "--prefix=/home/zlib" where libz.so is copied into /home/zlib in lib directory. later i copied "libz.so" to "$(PWD)/3rdparty/lib/zlib" so there is not compilation issues

Comment: @steeldriver can you please help me out with the solution

Comment: I wonder if it's because you built the *other* libraries first, and one of them pulls in the system version of libz? In particular, `libcurl.so.4` depends on `libz` I think

Comment: @steeldriver i have built in this order libz->openssl->curl thats correct rite?

Comment: So which libz.so do you see if you do `ldd /home/3rdparty/lib/curl/libcurl.so.4`?

Comment: @steeldriver, ldd 3rdparty/Platform_ARM_OSS/lib/curl/libcurl.so  
 libssl.so.1.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00000040018bc000)
 libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x0000004001958000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x0000004001be6000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000004001c10000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000004001c40000)
 /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000004000000000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000004001db3000)

Comment: Right - so it's you're build process for *that* that needs examination

Comment: @steeldriver means i need to change build order? can you please elaborate briefly on this?

Comment: @steeldriver what order should I give to compile zlib so that it has to take compiled path instead of standard path?

Comment: @steeldriver please let me know what is the order to build libz

Comment: Sorry - I don't have anything else to suggest